# Query optimization with polymorphic entities

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to optimize a complex query that deals with, among other things, 2 polymorphic entities (*materialable* and *markertable*). *Materialable* has 5 types of cases in it, and *marketable* has 4 types of cases.

So, the goal in this case is to connect *rebates* (~600k records) table with *xin_demand_plan_shiptos* (~3M records) table using both of those polymorphic entities as connectors. That is achieved with the query below. And it takes about 2 minutes to complete.

After countless trial-and-error optimization attempts, I resorted to splitting the query into 20 identical queries (= 5 x 4) that cover all possible polymorphism combinations on those entities, and linking their results with 19 *UNION ALL*.  The execution time dropped from 2 minutes to 1.2 seconds (with 1.0 second of it being used up by the optimizer).

That makes me think that there must be a way to re-rewrite the original query and/or add or delete indexing or optimization options to get to the same 1.2 seconds without copying the query 20 times. I'd welcome and appreciate any ideas

ORIGINAL QUERY:

```
select
    r.id            
    , c.period 
    , xdps.sku_id 
    , xdps.sold_to_point_id_indirect    
    , xdps.ship_to_point_id             
    , sum(xdps.forecast_units)          
    , sum(xdps.forecast_dollars)        
    , r.oi                              
    , r.rebate_type                     
    , r."value"                         
    , r.net_price                       
FROM rebates r 
INNER JOIN events e                     
    ON e.id = r.event_id
INNER JOIN markets m                    
    ON m.event_id = e.id
INNER JOIN calendar c                   
    ON c.type = 'monthly' 
        AND (c."to", c."from") overlaps (r.ship_start,r.ship_end)
INNER JOIN xin_demand_plan_shiptos xdps ON
        (
                (r.materialable_id = sku_id                 and materialable_type = 'Sku') 
            or  (r.materialable_id = promo_group_id         and materialable_type = 'PromoGroup') 
            or  (r.materialable_id = brand_id               and materialable_type = 'Brand') 
            or  (r.materialable_id = product_level_2_id     and materialable_type = 'ProductLevel2') 
            or  (r.materialable_id = lob_id                 and materialable_type = 'Lob')
        )           
    AND (r.lob_constraint = xdps.lob_id OR r.lob_constraint IS NULL)
    AND  
        (
                (m.marketable_id = xdps.sold_to_point_id_indirect AND m.marketable_type = 'SoldtoPoint')
            or  (m.marketable_id = xdps.sold_to_group_id_indirect AND m.marketable_type = 'SoldtoGroup')
            or  (m.marketable_id = xdps.ship_to_point_id          AND m.marketable_type = 'ShiptoPoint')
            or  (m.marketable_id = xdps.shipto_group_id           AND m.marketable_type = 'ShiptoGroup')
        )
    AND xdps."period"                               =  c."from"
    AND xdps."period" + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 DAY'  >= r.ship_start
    AND xdps."period"                               <= r.ship_end
WHERE       r.pos                       IS FALSE 
            AND r.id = any(array((select array_agg(id) from rebates where event_id = 24447)))  
GROUP BY    r.id
            , c.period
            , xdps.sku_id
            , e.beneficiary_definer 
            , e.beneficiary_if_someone_else
            , xdps.ship_to_point_id
            , xdps.shipto_group_id
            , xdps.sold_to_group_id_indirect
            , xdps.sold_to_point_id_indirect
```

Original query's EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=133628.70..133628.79 rows=4 width=81) (actual time=117542.764..117622.281 rows=70895 loops=1)
  Group Key: r.id, c.period, xdps.sku_id, e.beneficiary_definer, e.beneficiary_if_someone_else, xdps.ship_to_point_id, xdps.shipto_group_id, xdps.sold_to_group_id_indirect, xdps.sold_to_point_id_indirect
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=59.74..59.75 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.132..1.133 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Index Scan using index_rebates_on_event_id on rebates  (cost=0.55..59.62 rows=44 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.780 rows=751 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (event_id = 24447)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3642.86..133568.85 rows=4 width=81) (actual time=2979.937..117441.543 rows=70895 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (xdps.period = c."from")
        Join Filter: "overlaps"((c."to")::timestamp with time zone, (c."from")::timestamp with time zone, (r.ship_start)::timestamp with time zone, (r.ship_end)::timestamp with time zone)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3636.06..133561.70 rows=13 width=85) (actual time=2979.712..117341.178 rows=70895 loops=1)
              Join Filter: ((((r.lob_constraint)::text = (xdps.lob_id)::text) OR (r.lob_constraint IS NULL)) AND (xdps.period <= r.ship_end) AND ((xdps.period + '1 mon -1 days'::interval) >= r.ship_start) AND ((((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.sku_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'Sku'::text)) OR (((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.promo_group_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'PromoGroup'::text)) OR (((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.brand_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'Brand'::text)) OR (((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.product_level_2_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'ProductLevel2'::text)) OR (((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.lob_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'Lob'::text))))
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 61793481
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.25..54.25 rows=5 width=140) (actual time=1.275..29.227 rows=751 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..45.11 rows=7 width=131) (actual time=1.266..20.148 rows=751 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Scan using rebates_pkey on rebates r  (cost=0.42..26.61 rows=7 width=119) (actual time=1.259..11.174 rows=751 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (id = ANY ($0))
                                Filter: ((pos IS FALSE) AND (rebate_type = ANY ('{0,1,2,3}'::integer[])) AND (((materialable_type)::text = 'Sku'::text) OR ((materialable_type)::text = 'PromoGroup'::text) OR ((materialable_type)::text = 'Brand'::text) OR ((materialable_type)::text = 'ProductLevel2'::text) OR ((materialable_type)::text = 'Lob'::text)))
                          ->  Index Scan using index_events_on_id_readable_id on events e  (cost=0.41..2.63 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=751)
                                Index Cond: (id = r.event_id)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using markets_event_id_marketable_id_marketable_type_idx on markets m  (cost=0.41..1.30 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.007..0.009 rows=1 loops=751)
                          Index Cond: (event_id = e.id)
                          Filter: (((marketable_type)::text = 'SoldtoPoint'::text) OR ((marketable_type)::text = 'SoldtoGroup'::text) OR ((marketable_type)::text = 'ShiptoPoint'::text) OR ((marketable_type)::text = 'ShiptoGroup'::text))
                          Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on xin_demand_plan_shiptos xdps  (cost=3634.81..26695.87 rows=125 width=85) (actual time=11.370..85.191 rows=82376 loops=751)
                    Recheck Cond: (((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_point_id_indirect)::text) OR ((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_group_id_indirect)::text) OR ((m.marketable_id)::text = (ship_to_point_id)::text) OR ((m.marketable_id)::text = (shipto_group_id)::text))
                    Filter: ((((m.marketable_type)::text = 'SoldtoPoint'::text) AND ((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_point_id_indirect)::text)) OR (((m.marketable_type)::text = 'SoldtoGroup'::text) AND ((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_group_id_indirect)::text)) OR (((m.marketable_type)::text = 'ShiptoPoint'::text) AND ((m.marketable_id)::text = (ship_to_point_id)::text)) OR (((m.marketable_type)::text = 'ShiptoGroup'::text) AND ((m.marketable_id)::text = (shipto_group_id)::text)))
                    Heap Blocks: exact=6970031
                    ->  BitmapOr  (cost=3634.81..3634.81 rows=25011 width=0) (actual time=9.862..9.862 rows=0 loops=751)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on xin_demand_plan_shiptos_sold_to_point_id_indirect_idx  (cost=0.00..19.46 rows=1766 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=751)
                                Index Cond: ((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_point_id_indirect)::text)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on xin_demand_plan_shiptos_sold_to_group_id_indirect_idx  (cost=0.00..79.11 rows=8178 width=0) (actual time=6.457..6.457 rows=82376 loops=751)
                                Index Cond: ((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_group_id_indirect)::text)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_xin_demand_plan_shiptos_on_ship_to_point_id  (cost=0.00..444.66 rows=1439 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=751)
                                Index Cond: ((m.marketable_id)::text = (ship_to_point_id)::text)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_xin_demand_plan_shiptos_on_shipto_group_id  (cost=0.00..3091.45 rows=13627 width=0) (actual time=3.384..3.384 rows=45284 loops=751)
                                Index Cond: ((m.marketable_id)::text = (shipto_group_id)::text)
        ->  Hash  (cost=4.40..4.40 rows=192 width=16) (actual time=0.205..0.205 rows=192 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB
              ->  Seq Scan on calendar c  (cost=0.00..4.40 rows=192 width=16) (actual time=0.008..0.126 rows=192 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((type)::text = 'monthly'::text)
Planning time: 8.031 ms
Execution time: 117649.466 ms
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the query when re-written as 20 UNION ALL queries:
showing only one sub-plan out of 20 (they look the same) but this one does all the work for this particular polymorphic combination

```
    Append  (cost=3207.43..123158.92 rows=22 width=152) (actual time=551.503..764.736 rows=70895 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                         
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 6"  (cost=76.85..76.88 rows=1 width=152) (actual time=18.680..18.749 rows=45 loops=1)                                                                                                                                         
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=76.85..76.87 rows=1 width=81) (actual time=18.678..18.713 rows=45 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                    
              Group Key: r_5.id, c_5.period, xdps_5.sku_id, e_5.beneficiary_definer, e_5.beneficiary_if_someone_else, xdps_5.ship_to_point_id, xdps_5.shipto_group_id, xdps_5.sold_to_group_id_indirect, xdps_5.sold_to_point_id_indirect                      
              InitPlan 6 (returns $25)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                ->  Aggregate  (cost=18.75..18.76 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.672..0.672 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                    
                      ->  Index Only Scan using rebates_event_rebate_idx on rebates rebates_5  (cost=0.42..16.87 rows=751 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.343 rows=751 loops=1)                                                                                 
                            Index Cond: (event_id = 24447)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                            Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.83..58.07 rows=1 width=81) (actual time=17.663..18.595 rows=45 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                 
                    Join Filter: "overlaps"((c_5."to")::timestamp with time zone, (c_5."from")::timestamp with time zone, (r_5.ship_start)::timestamp with time zone, (r_5.ship_end)::timestamp with time zone)                                                
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.69..57.88 rows=1 width=85) (actual time=17.648..18.407 rows=45 loops=1)                                                                                                                                           
                          Join Filter: (r_5.event_id = e_5.id)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.27..56.37 rows=1 width=85) (actual time=17.635..18.212 rows=45 loops=1)                                                                                                                                     
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..37.38 rows=5 width=57) (actual time=0.706..5.561 rows=751 loops=1)                                                                                                                                
                                      ->  Index Scan using rebates_pkey on rebates r_5  (cost=0.42..26.50 rows=7 width=47) (actual time=0.699..2.776 rows=751 loops=1)                                                                                         
                                            Index Cond: (id = ANY ($25))                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                            Filter: ((pos IS FALSE) AND ((materialable_type)::text = 'Sku'::text) AND (rebate_type = ANY ('{0,1,2,3}'::integer[])))                                                                                            
                                      ->  Index Only Scan using markets_event_id_marketable_id_marketable_type_idx on markets m_5  (cost=0.41..1.55 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=751)                                               
                                            Index Cond: ((event_id = r_5.event_id) AND (marketable_type = 'SoldtoGroup'::text))                                                                                                                                
                                            Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                ->  Index Scan using xin_demand_plan_shiptos_sold_to_group_id_indirect_sku_id_idx on xin_demand_plan_shiptos xdps_5  (cost=0.43..3.79 rows=1 width=59) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=0 loops=751)                             
                                      Index Cond: (((sold_to_group_id_indirect)::text = (m_5.marketable_id)::text) AND ((sku_id)::text = (r_5.materialable_id)::text))                                                                                         
                                      Filter: ((((r_5.lob_constraint)::text = (lob_id)::text) OR (r_5.lob_constraint IS NULL)) AND (period <= r_5.ship_end) AND ((period + '1 mon -1 days'::interval) >= r_5.ship_start))                                      
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 11                                                                                                                                                                                               
                          ->  Index Scan using events_pkey on events e_5  (cost=0.41..1.49 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=45)                                                                                                         
                                Index Cond: (id = m_5.event_id)                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    ->  Index Scan using "from+period" on calendar c_5  (cost=0.14..0.17 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=45)                                                                                                           
                          Index Cond: ("from" = xdps_5.period)
```

Comment: Is the `AND (r.lob_constraint = xdps.lob_id OR r.lob_constraint IS NULL)` condition really necessary? Cant you move it to the `or  (r.materialable_id = lob_id                 and materialable_type = 'Lob')` condition ?

Comment: could you provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/ to make some test ? (or the create table and some data)

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, the r.lob_constraint is needed where it is, and can’t be moved up as suggested. But it is really light and has a Boolean based index.  Even completely taking it out doesn’t move the needle.

Comment: @Blag I will give it shot, but not sure I’ll succeed given the number and size of tables involved

Comment: `(cost=3642.86..133568.85 rows=4 width=81) (actual time=2979.937..117441.543 rows=70895 loops=1)` There is a huge difference in expected vs observed number of rows. Do you have valid statistics?

Comment: @wildpasser After your question, I ran `VACUUM ANALYZE`, nothing changed. Then I changed `default_statistics_target` to 10,000 and ran `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE`: The first query's time went down from 120 to 23 seconds, and the second query's time went down to from  700ms to 58ms.

Comment: IMHO, the real problem is is that your type-tag `materialable_type` is a low-cardinality column. (and the *smart-union* type of model (Johnson&Johnson) does not work that well anyway.

Comment: You're probably right. The solution I described turned out to be very fragile.  Minor changes to the query parameters have been leading to very volatile execution paths, from 80ms to 20 seconds.  I've ended up splitting materialable_id into 5 columns and marketable_id into 4 columns, instead of trying to mark them with type-tags, trying to be more transparent to the optimizer.  That resulted in 1.3 seconds execution paths pretty consistently.  But still much longer than ~60ms that I currently get with 20 UNION ALL version.

Answer (score 0):

After even more experimentation, I somehow got the time of the original query to 80ms.  I'm not sure what exactly worked, but I suspect that was the introduction of several multi-column indexes that I built using the logical path that I personally would follow if I "were" the optimizer, using my intuition for underlying data. Interestingly, if I take out the line `AND r.rebate_type IN (0,1,2,3)`, which should be inconsequential for the result in this test case, the execution time jumps to 5 seconds.

The resulting query:

```
explain analyze
select
    r.id            
    , c.period 
    , xdps.sku_id 
    , xdps.sold_to_point_id_indirect    
    , xdps.ship_to_point_id             
    , sum(xdps.forecast_units)          
    , sum(xdps.forecast_dollars)        
    , r.oi                              
    , r.rebate_type                     
    , r."value"                         
    , r.net_price                       
FROM rebates r 
INNER JOIN events e     ON e.id = r.event_id
INNER JOIN markets m    ON m.event_id = e.id
INNER JOIN calendar c   ON c.type = 'monthly' AND c."to" >= r.ship_start and c.from <= r.ship_end
INNER JOIN xin_demand_plan_shiptos xdps ON
        (
                (r.materialable_id = sku_id                 and materialable_type = 'Sku') 
            or  (r.materialable_id = promo_group_id         and materialable_type = 'PromoGroup') 
            or  (r.materialable_id = brand_id               and materialable_type = 'Brand') 
            or  (r.materialable_id = product_level_2_id     and materialable_type = 'ProductLevel2') 
            or  (r.materialable_id = lob_id                 and materialable_type = 'Lob')
        )           
    AND (r.lob_constraint = xdps.lob_id OR r.lob_constraint IS NULL)
    AND  
        (
                (m.marketable_id = xdps.sold_to_point_id_indirect AND m.marketable_type = 'SoldtoPoint')
            or  (m.marketable_id = xdps.sold_to_group_id_indirect AND m.marketable_type = 'SoldtoGroup')
            or  (m.marketable_id = xdps.ship_to_point_id          AND m.marketable_type = 'ShiptoPoint')
            or  (m.marketable_id = xdps.shipto_group_id           AND m.marketable_type = 'ShiptoGroup')
        )
    AND xdps."period"                               =  c."from"
    AND xdps."period" + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 DAY'  >= r.ship_start
    AND xdps."period"                               <= r.ship_end
WHERE       r.pos               IS false
            AND r.rebate_type IN (0,1,2,3) --including lump_sum
            AND r.event_id =    24447  
GROUP BY    r.id
            , c.period
            , xdps.sku_id
            , e.beneficiary_definer 
            , e.beneficiary_if_someone_else
            , xdps.ship_to_point_id
            , xdps.shipto_group_id
            , xdps.sold_to_group_id_indirect
            , xdps.sold_to_point_id_indirect
```

Its EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=15038.39..15038.84 rows=30 width=80) (actual time=82.779..82.814 rows=45 loops=1)
  Group Key: r.id, c.period, xdps.sku_id, e.beneficiary_definer, e.beneficiary_if_someone_else, xdps.ship_to_point_id, xdps.shipto_group_id, xdps.sold_to_group_id_indirect, xdps.sold_to_point_id_indirect
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=11688.17..15037.57 rows=30 width=80) (actual time=80.854..82.702 rows=45 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (c."from" = xdps.period)
        Join Filter: ((((r.lob_constraint)::text = (xdps.lob_id)::text) OR (r.lob_constraint IS NULL)) AND (xdps.period <= r.ship_end) AND ((xdps.period + '1 mon -1 days'::interval) >= r.ship_start) AND ((((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.sku_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'Sku'::text)) OR (((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.promo_group_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'PromoGroup'::text)) OR (((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.brand_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'Brand'::text)) OR (((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.product_level_2_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'ProductLevel2'::text)) OR (((r.materialable_id)::text = (xdps.lob_id)::text) AND ((r.materialable_type)::text = 'Lob'::text))))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1117
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=11.52..2672.96 rows=11883 width=63) (actual time=30.190..30.367 rows=2 loops=1)
              Join Filter: ((c."to" >= r.ship_start) AND (c."from" <= r.ship_end))
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 36047
              ->  Index Scan using "from" on calendar c  (cost=0.14..7.80 rows=192 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.056 rows=49 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((type)::text = 'monthly'::text)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=11.37..795.03 rows=557 width=51) (actual time=0.003..0.298 rows=736 loops=49)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on rebates r  (cost=11.37..792.25 rows=557 width=51) (actual time=0.120..1.140 rows=751 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (event_id = 24447)
                          Filter: ((pos IS FALSE) AND (rebate_type = ANY ('{0,1,2,3}'::integer[])) AND (((materialable_type)::text = 'Sku'::text) OR ((materialable_type)::text = 'PromoGroup'::text) OR ((materialable_type)::text = 'Brand'::text) OR ((materialable_type)::text = 'ProductLevel2'::text) OR ((materialable_type)::text = 'Lob'::text)))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=312
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on rebates_event_id_rebate_type_pos_oi_idx  (cost=0.00..11.24 rows=716 width=0) (actual time=0.081..0.081 rows=751 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((event_id = 24447) AND (pos = false))
        ->  Sort  (cost=11165.28..11167.73 rows=978 width=96) (actual time=43.627..47.199 rows=8873 loops=1)
              Sort Key: xdps.period
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1632kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=125.70..11116.71 rows=978 width=96) (actual time=3.979..36.881 rows=8873 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.83..4.21 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.029..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Scan using index_events_on_id_readable_id on events e  (cost=0.41..2.66 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (id = 24447)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using markets_event_id_marketable_id_marketable_type_idx on markets m  (cost=0.41..1.54 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.011..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (event_id = 24447)
                                Filter: (((marketable_type)::text = 'SoldtoPoint'::text) OR ((marketable_type)::text = 'SoldtoGroup'::text) OR ((marketable_type)::text = 'ShiptoPoint'::text) OR ((marketable_type)::text = 'ShiptoGroup'::text))
                                Heap Fetches: 0
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on xin_demand_plan_shiptos xdps  (cost=124.87..11111.93 rows=57 width=84) (actual time=3.944..29.858 rows=8873 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_point_id_indirect)::text) OR ((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_group_id_indirect)::text) OR ((m.marketable_id)::text = (ship_to_point_id)::text) OR ((m.marketable_id)::text = (shipto_group_id)::text))
                          Filter: ((((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_point_id_indirect)::text) AND ((m.marketable_type)::text = 'SoldtoPoint'::text)) OR (((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_group_id_indirect)::text) AND ((m.marketable_type)::text = 'SoldtoGroup'::text)) OR (((m.marketable_id)::text = (ship_to_point_id)::text) AND ((m.marketable_type)::text = 'ShiptoPoint'::text)) OR (((m.marketable_id)::text = (shipto_group_id)::text) AND ((m.marketable_type)::text = 'ShiptoGroup'::text)))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 29424
                          Heap Blocks: exact=4278
                          ->  BitmapOr  (cost=124.87..124.87 rows=11426 width=0) (actual time=3.295..3.295 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on xin_demand_plan_shiptos_sold_to_point_id_indirect_idx  (cost=0.00..6.97 rows=579 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_point_id_indirect)::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on xin_demand_plan_shiptos_sold_to_group_id_indirect_idx  (cost=0.00..29.43 rows=2693 width=0) (actual time=0.878..0.878 rows=8873 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((m.marketable_id)::text = (sold_to_group_id_indirect)::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_xin_demand_plan_shiptos_on_ship_to_point_id  (cost=0.00..12.59 rows=1035 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((m.marketable_id)::text = (ship_to_point_id)::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_xin_demand_plan_shiptos_on_shipto_group_id  (cost=0.00..75.82 rows=7119 width=0) (actual time=2.391..2.391 rows=31428 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((m.marketable_id)::text = (shipto_group_id)::text)
Planning time: 20.265 ms
Execution time: 82.994 ms
```